# Unknown Action: The action 'create' could not be found for CommentsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app that allows users to comment on a single "work" (think blog post). The associations in the models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works  
  has_many :comments

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :work
```

There's a form on the Works show page that allows users to post a comment:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post a comment!" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The Works controller is as follows. Note that I'm adding the build comment functionality here so that the form on the Works page functions:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController
   #before_filter :current_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @works = Work.all
    @comment = @work.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @works }
end
end
def create
    @work = current_user.works.create(params[:work])
    redirect_to current_user
  end

def edit
    @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @work = current_user.works.new
end

def destroy
  @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Work deleted"
  redirect_to current_user
end

 def update
    @work = current_user.works.find(params[:id])
    if @work.update_attributes(params[:work])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def show 
  @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  @comment = @work.comments.build
  @comment.user = current_user
  @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Work", trackable_id: @work).all
  @comments = @work.comments.order("created_at DESC").where(work_id: @work ).all 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @work }
    end
  end
end
```

And lastly, here is the Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Comment", trackable_id: @comment).all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
  end

  def update
     @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      flash[:success] = "Comment updated"
      redirect_to @comment
    end
  end

  def create
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @work.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      #flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render 'home#index'
    end
  end
  end
end
```

When I attempt to submit a comment using the comment form on the works show view page, I get the following error:

**Unknown action
The action 'create' could not be found for CommentsController**

Why can't it find the create action on the Comments controller? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments controller `show` action is missing an `end`, i.e. this:

```
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Comment", trackable_id: @comment).all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
  end
```

should be this:

```
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where(trackable_type: "Comment", trackable_id: @comment).all
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
    end
  end
```

(right now it is 'falling' into the create action so the create action never gets set up).

You will then probably need to change the final:

```
    end
  end
  end
end
```

to be

```
    end
  end
end
```

as this was probably 'compensating' for the mismatch and allowing the page to precompile in Ruby.

Comment: +1 making the indentation of the code consistent would have shown the problem straight away.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I definitely learned from this rookie mistake! I'm getting a new error (Couldn't find Work without an ID) but this solved the problem I posted. I'm getting closer!